# How to get bitcoincharts weighted prices via Json and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to get Jquery to read a json file,

But unfortunately I can not get it to work.

**This is my json file.** see: http://bitcoincharts.com/t/weighted_prices.json

```
{
    "USD": {"7d": "4.4549", "30d": "5.2016", "24h": "4.1373"}, 
    "GBP": {"7d": "2.9706", "30d": "3.2620", "24h": "2.5463"}, 
}
```

**My jquery script looks like this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (document).ready(function(){
       $.getJSON('http://bitcoincharts.com/t/weighted_prices.json',function(data){
               $("#results").html(data[0].30d);
       });
});
</script>
```

I try to grab USD>30d>**5.2016**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get USD -> 30d (= 5.2016) you need to do this:

```
data["USD"]["30d"]
```

You can't say `data[0]` because using a numeric index is (generally) only applicable to arrays and you don't have an array. You have an object with two properties, "USD" and "GBP", and each of those properties has an object with the properties "7D", "30d", "24h".

In more detail:

JavaScript *array* literal declarations use square brackets that contain simply a list of elements, like this:

```
var myArray = ["a","b","c"];
```

But *object* literal declarations use curly brackets with key-value pairs like in the JSON you provided in your question, or here's a simpler example:

```
var myObject = { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3" };
```

The "trick" is that once defined both arrays and objects are accessed with the square bracket notation, but arrays use numeric indexes and objects use string keys.

You can also use dot notation like you were trying to do, but only on properties with a key name that meets the rules of valid JavaScript identifiers, i.e., not starting with a number, no spaces, not a reserved word, etc. These restrictions only apply to dot notation though, so if you use the square bracket notation you can have spaces, numbers, etc.

It's fine to nest arrays and objects, including mixing the two, but in your particular case you just had an object containing two other objects, no arrays.

So `data["USD"]` will give you `{"7d": "4.4549", "30d": "5.2016", "24h": "4.1373"}`.

`data["GBP"]` will give you `{"7d": "2.9706", "30d": "3.2620", "24h": "2.5463"}`.

You narrow it down to the individual value you want with `data["USD"]["30d"]`.

**EDIT: Your `$.getJSON` request isn't going to work because of the Ajax same-origin policy, i.e., you are only allowed to make JSON requests to the same domain as the current page's.**

You could try JSONP - which jQuery supports with practically no effort on your part: you just have to add `?callback=?` to the end of the url - except that JSONP requires support on the server and it looks like the bitcoin people don't support it.

So the easiest way forward is to get the data in *your* server side code where the same-origin policy won't get in your way.

Comment: Cool thank you very much for the detailed explanation ;)
It works local (data.json) But if I insert "http://bitcoincharts.com/t/weighted_prices.json" in the $.getJSON function, Then it does not work :( see this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/722830/

Comment: See my edit. I think the problem is that Ajax doesn't work across domains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time finding the reference at the moment, but the problem is that you can't access the key via dot notation, you need to access it via array notation. In your case...

```
data[0]["30d"]
```

Comment: Hmm... Does it work on your computer if you save it in a ".html" file? I can not see the prices in my browser :(